# Intuitive meaning of Matsubara frequencies

Tags: condensed-matter

I have a somewhat nebulous question but I hope you'll bear with me. I am trying to understand about how to think about Matsubara frequencies and the imaginary time formalism in an intuitive way. That is, if I have a function $f(i\epsilon_n)$ of the Mastubara frequency $\epsilon_n$, is there some intuition regarding what the values of the function for different n's and its corresponding Fourier transform implies physically?

To clarify what I mean, in the case of real-time, I can think of $f(\epsilon_n)$ as a Fourier series, with everything this implies: For example, a slow decay of $f$ as a function of $n$ implies that the function $f(t) = \sum_n e^{i\epsilon_n t} f(i\epsilon_n)$ is rapidly oscillating inside one period, and this might mean something if it describes something physical. Also, we know that if $f(z)$ is a Green's function which is analytic in the UHP we can continue $f(i\epsilon_n)$ to a retarded Green's function and similarly for the LHP to the advanced. Why is there this relation between the sign of $\epsilon_n$ and the causality?

A generic imaginary time function is the some superposition of exponentials, which in real time correspond to decay. But is there anything I can learn from the way it decays? Presumably this has something to do with thermal fluctuations, but in what way?

Mind you, I understand of course that there an inverse relation between temperature and the period of the function, and thus between the period and thermal fluctuations, but I want to understand what happens on a single period. It's just very hard for me to work with something which is currently for me just a mathematical trick that doesn't seem to mean anything physically.